# React native build on real device crashes (emul working)

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Can anybody advice on what I'm doing wrong here?

When launching the app through `XCode (9.2)` emulator the app works fine, when building it on a real device (`iOS 11.2.6`) it throws the error further:
Tried the steps described here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4831

```
2018-03-20 12:05:22.400152+0500 qatar[1134:528934] *** Terminating app due to uncaught 
exception 'RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: 
TypeError: babelHelpers.objectDestructuringEmpty is not a function. 
(In 'babelHelpers.objectDestructuringEmpty(e)', 
'babelHelpers.objectDestructuringEmpty' is undefined)

This error is located at:
in Unknown
in t
in Connect(t)
in RCTView
in t
in RCTView
in RCTView
in RCTView
in t
in t
in t
in Connect(t)
in t
in RCTView
in n
in t
in n
in RCTView
in RCTView
in t
in RCTView
in e
in r
in Unknown
in n
in n
in t
in t
in withCachedChildNavigation(t)
in Unknown
in n
in RCTView
in n
in RCTView
in t
in t
in Unknown
in n
in n
in RCTView
in t
in Styled(t)
in n
in Unknown
in t
in Translate(Component)
in t
in RCTView
in RCTView
in t', reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError: babelHelpers.objectDestructuringEmpty is..., stack:
default@738:198
<unknown>@46:29910
q@46:47194
ee@46:47795
ne@46:48869
le@46:51343
enqueueSetState@46:25514
setState@53:915
dispatch@857:822
<unknown>@855:668
b@23:628
callTimers@23:2773
value@18:3078
<unknown>@18:812
value@18:2507
value@18:784
```

A similar error is given by Android:

[image: Android error]

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a bundle.js file?
Try this:

```
react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/AppName/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest='./ios'
```

Can you give more informations about your .babelrc File?

Answer (score 0):

I got this fix upon installing babel helper plugin.

```
Package.json:
"devDependencies": {
"babel-cli": "6.26.0",
"babel-plugin-external-helpers": "^6.22.0",
....
}

babelrc:
{
"presets": ["react-native", "flow"],
"plugins": [
"external-helpers",
...
]
}
```

Reference to install this plugin:
`https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-external-helpers`

Comment: I am facing this issue, I'm a bit perturbed by how everyone in the other threads just says to "remove empty destructures from your code". It's a perfectly valid thing to do.  As one stubs out methods it's useful. 

Adding the plugin here I suppose has helped, as I now get the crash on the emulator, in addition to the phone. As opposed to just the phone before (which was a nasty surprise).  I'll take that.  But I would like this to be gone so I can use 

const {

} = this.props;

Comment: ^ that appears to be fixed with the move to RN 0.57 and some other compatible deps. I can now use the language correctly. 

dev deps: `"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.48.3", "react-test-renderer": "^16.6.0-alpha.8af6728",`
deps: `"react": "^16.6.0-alpha.8af6728", "react-native": "0.57.4",`

 .babelrc: `"plugins": [ [ "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset" ] ] `